# Unsure why First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

This should be quite straight forward, but I can't seem to be able to pin point the exact cause for the error.

Here is the scenario:

1. User fills in the form.
2. In the nested attributes, user submits form with more than 3 bounties. This triggers "rescue ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords".
3. User should be redirected back to the form while maintaining all previously entered information.

Here is how the code looks like:

posts/new/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

posts_controller.html.erb

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
    @bounty = Bounty.new
  end

def create
    begin
      @post = Post.new(post_params) 
      @post.creator = current_user
      if @post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your post was created."
        redirect_to posts_path
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Opps, something went wrong.'        
        render :new
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords
      flash[:error] = 'Too many bounties.'
      render :new
    end
  end
```

But the code above creates "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error when "TooManyRecords" error is triggered. On the other hand, error for "Opps, something went wrong." is working just fine.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords
  flash[:error] = 'Too many bounties.'
  @post = Post.new
  @bounty = Bounty.new
  render :new
end
```

You have to initialize the @post variable for your 'new' form before you render it.  Since the exception occurs in the Post.new(post_params) call, @post is currently nil when you render the form.

This version will wipe the info from the form.  To preserve that info, you'll need to call Post.new with a modified version of post_params that strips out the bounties.  I can't tell you how that should look without knowing the details of your params.

Comment: you mean `post_param` will be wiped on `rescue` method ? How about keeping the `post_param` value into another variable and use it back again ?

Comment: Hey thanks, your input removed the error. Here is the post params info:   def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :url, :story, :postreview, :targets, :image, :description, :category_ids, bounties_attributes: [:title, :signups, :description, :_destroy])
  end

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I decided not to pursue the rescue path. Instead, created a custom validation for this. Not, the info is preserved in addition to preventing the users from adding more than 3 nested attributes. Problem Solved.

```
  validate :bounty_limit

  def bounty_limit
    errors.add(:base, "You sir, are generous for planning to give more than 3!") if bounties.size > 3
  end
```

But @PeterGoldstein, thank you for answering my question.